# How can I change the state for both buttons in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a friend request box where I have to options: accept and decline.

I have the following code in react:

```
const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState('Accept');
const [declineText, setDeclineText] = useState('Decline');
function handleClick() {

if ( buttonText != declineText ) {
    setButtonText('You accepted the friend request');
    setDeclineText('');
  } else {
    setDeclineText('You declined the friend request');
    setButtonText('');
  }
}

<button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary" id="accept">
        {buttonText}
</button>

 <button onClick={handleClick}className="btn" id="decline">
       {declineText}
 </button>
```

I know something is wrong because I receive only the first option with "You accepted..." when I'm clicking on any of them. What should I do to include both cases "You accepted...", respectively "You declined..."

Comment: 1. Why would you use the same handler for 2 different things? 2. Why would you change the text of a button to an empty string?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the structure of the code can further be refactored to solve the issues mentioned by `Konrad Linkowski`, here's a working version that uses the `id` of these 2 buttons to toggle between `Accept` and `Decline` states:

```
export default function App() {

  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Accept");
  const [declineText, setDeclineText] = useState("Decline");

  function handleClick(e) {
    if ( e.target.id === "accept" ) {
      setButtonText("You accepted the friend request");
      setDeclineText("");
    } else {
      setDeclineText("You declined the friend request");
      setButtonText("");
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary" id="accept">
        {buttonText}
      </button>

      <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn" id="decline">
        {declineText}
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Here's another, cleaner approach with just one state and a message box:

```
export default function App() {

  const [ message, setMessage ] = useState(null);

  function handleClick(e) {
    if ( e.target.id === "accept" ) {
      return setMessage("You accepted the friend request");
    }
    setMessage("You declined the friend request");
  }

  return (
    <>
      {/* Show buttons only if the user has not yet accepted or declined. If you remove this conditional, then the buttons will still be available for subsequent toggling between Accept and Decline states. It's up to you: */}
      { !message && (
        <>
        <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn btn-primary" id="accept">
          Accept
        </button>
        <button onClick={handleClick} className="btn" id="decline">
          Decline
        </button>
        </>
      )}
      {/* Show the message only if the user has accepted or declined: */}
      { message && <div>{message}</div> } 
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you! that's what i've wanted to do

Comment: You're welcome. Happy hacking! :)